# raspberry pi gmail sign in blocked by google

Tags: email, raspberry-pi

I want to send automated emails form my raspberry pi. I followed this guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP

I got an error when trying to send an email

```
    ~>cat tmp.txt | mail -s "subject" -t EXAMPLE@gmail.com
    mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

I also got an email from Google telling me a sign-in attempt was prevented because I wasn't using modern security standards: [image]

Should I be using a different was of sending email or should I use a different email service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to that gmail account setting and look for "Allow less secure apps" and turn it on.

```
myaccount.google.com -> "Sign-in & security" -> "Allow less secure apps: ON"
```

That will allow you to send email with less secure login process.

[image]

Otherwise, I saw some post which said [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Send_an_email#Python) helped on python 2.7

Ref: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=94023&p=659005

Answer (score 1):

Enable **Less Secure Apps** doesn't help for me.

However I found that if I turn on [2-factor auth](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthSettings#devices) and set a [app-specific password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords?hl=en&pli=1) then I can successfully log in to my gmail account.